# Cast decimals into floats in py connector

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I'm working on a project involving querying data from a snowflake server (through python connector).

As part of it, I want fetch query results as pandas dataframe.
I was wondering if there is a way of telling the connector to always cast any `DECIMAL` or `NUMBER` value to a `FLOAT` value. So ideally - the df would contain instances of `flaot` or `np.float` in stead of `decimal.Decimal`.

I saw the `arrow_number_to_decimal` option and have tried it (see snippet) below but it seems that it still returns a `DECIMAL`.

```py
import snowflake.connector, decimal
c = snowflake.connector.connect(..., arrow_number_to_decimal=False)
with c.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("""SELECT AVG(a) as bla from (select 1 as a union all select 29 as a union select 77 as a )""")
    df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
x = df.squeeze()
assert not isinstance(x, decimal.Decimal)
```

Connector version I'm using is `2.7.5`

(PS - I know I can cast using the raw sql I submit through the driver / cast after df has been assigned. I wanna make sure the connector has no feature which can help in the matter)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ever find anything to help resolve your issue? I am running into something similar and hoping to find something.

Comment: @Saltz3 yes - see suggested answer of mine

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I managed to get the outcome I wanted using this approach:

```
def is_decimal_dt(c) -> bool:
    """
    Determines if given snowflake dtype is decimal or not
    https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric
    """
    data_type = snowflake.connector.constants.FIELD_ID_TO_NAME[c.type_code]
    return data_type.lower() in ("fixed", "number", "dec", "decimal", "numeric")


with ... as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(some_sql)
        dec_cols = [col.name for col in cur.description if is_decimal_dt(col)]
        df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
if dec_cols:
    df[dec_cols] = df[dec_cols].astype(np.float64)
```